# Is there a way to export checkbox values from a PDF using Aspose.PDF C#?

Tags: c#, aspose.pdf

I am trying to ingest a PDF file from my local machine however, I am having trouble ingesting the values of check boxes from the PDF. I see that there is a method using iTextSharp, however, I was hoping there was a way to use it with Aspose.

Most of the export values of the pdf will most likely be /1 or /OFF, however I am getting no value.

Comment: can you provide the raw encoding for the PDF for this section so we can see what we're dealing with; as well as a screenshot of the PDF in this area?

Comment: You can retrieve the values of check boxes with Aspose.PDF for .NET API, provided the form is intact. Therefore, please elaborate the approach you have tried so far, which is not working, along with your source document so that I may investigate further and help you out. **PS**: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.